# Add dynamically created String into Spring Context

Tags: spring, spring-boot, dependency-injection, applicationcontext

I am creating a String based on some input parameters when a rest call is executed. I have created my own Annotation to intercept certain methods which will be called later on (within the same request). The Interceptor needs to know the String created at the beginning. My initial thought was to add the String into the Spring context like this:

```
 ConfigurableListableBeanFactory beanFactory = ((ConfigurableApplicationContext) context).getBeanFactory();
 beanFactory.registerSingleton("myValue", "generatedString");
```

And just inject it to the interceptor. However i can only add it once this way and i really dont want it to be a singleton. Each request has its own "generatedString". I could not find a suitable way of solving this. What i actually want is to register an object on runtime for the current thread so i can inject it later on. When the Thread is done it should disappear.

Comment: not sure what your requirement is. But isn't ThredLocal an option?

Comment: Thanks. I actually implemented a static holder with a thread local as alternative. So i guess it is the way to go.